# How to add an email address to a website's URL using the PARAMS element?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Let me explain the process leading to my issue: I want to send an email to a person. When this person receives the email and clicks on a button, they are redirected to a page. I would like that when the person clicks on the button, their email address is retrieved (regardless of the email client) and sent in the URL of the page (for example: testsite.com/?emlct=test@mysite.com) in order to later retrieve this information to automatically fill in an email field.

I try to add a params on link button like that : [https://testsite.com/?emlct=[Email]](https://testsite.com/?emlct=%5BEmail%5D) and after add the email in email field with this code :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var u = new URL(window.location);
  var e = u.searchParams.get('emlct');
 $('#email-field-id').val(e);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You seem to have two different query parameters - one says `email=`, the other `emlct=` - is that the issue? Or are you trying to execute JavaScript in the email to retrieve the email? That's not going to be possible. Or is it something else?

Comment: Do you have trouble adding the email to an URL (like stated in your title) or retrieving it and setting it on an element (like in your code)? Are those quotes ´‘` `’` in your code? Any errors?

Comment: The code I past is just for exemple, the query param was emlct=, i fixed this grammar issue.

Yes i'm trying to execute JS on the email to retrieve the email and after send it in the query param url. Is any other solution to get email adress and send it to url ?

Comment: I try to retrieve email adresse and send it on element.

I think the quote was mistake when i past the code.

Comment: You already know the recipient's email and could simply add it when you generate the email body

Comment: Sure, but then, how do I make sure that the email address is directed to the "param" element of the URL?

Let's say the email address is: test@site.fr. If I display it in the body of the email, how can I ensure that when a button is clicked, the opened page has the parameter: ?emlct=test@site.fr?

Comment: By putting that URL, including this parameter, into the `href` attribute of your "link button"?

Comment: How is the email being sent to the person?